# Logstash and Grok always show _grokparsefailure

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

I am using https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to build grok filters for logstash, but even though grokdebug shows corrected parsed message, my kibana showing `_grokparsefailure`

`message` [2015-12-01 08:53:16] app.INFO: Calories 4 [] [] 
`pattern` %{SYSLOG5424SD} %{JAVACLASS}: %{WORD} %{INT} %{GREEDYDATA}

[image: kibana]
[image: logstash.conf]
What am I doing wrong? Notice that first filter with tag "google" and GREEDYDATA works, and second always fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution. Correct pattern is:
`\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] %{DATA}%{LOGLEVEL:level}: Calories %{WORD:calories_count} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}` 
Even tough I used https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com to find the pattern, it was completely irrelevant.

Comment: The debugger's "Discover" feature really makes a wild guess on the types, based on only one input sample.  It's better to set the patterns specifically, as you did.